# Strange PHP misbehaviour in case of radio buttons

Tags: php

This is html form;

```
<div class="formText">
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="100" onclick="uncheck();"/>100
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="200" onclick="uncheck();"/>200
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="500" onclick="uncheck();"/>500
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="other" onclick="check(this);"/>other
    <input type="text" name="other_field" id="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
```

Here is php coding

```
if(isset($_POST['txtNumber']))
    {
        $choice_no = $_POST["txtNumber"];
    }
```

& insert query
    $insert = "INSERT INTO dbForm (db_number) VALUES ('{$choice_no}')";

Now this form displays 4 radio options, 3 are fixed and one is hidden. The last one is visible when the guy clicks on "other" radio button.

Now when above three radio buttons with value 100, 200 or 500 are chosen, they are good and the values are going into database.

Using this code it is not picking the value of "other" field and always inserting "0" in database.. 
Surprised I m.

Comment: Please add your php code

Comment: See the value of the 4th button is `value="other"`. Do you save it in the database as `int` or `varchar\char` ?

Comment: @bborisovs i saved it in db as int.. cuz the value of other will always be a number picked up from textfield

Comment: @TobiasZander code added

Comment: And where do you grab the "other_field" value in your PHP code above?

Comment: @OneManCrew php code added

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ the other field code opens up a new text field and the data is to be inserted in that text field.. the data can be numbers only

Comment: Sorry but unless we see that code how can we know whats wrong with it

Comment: Try to change `value="other"` to `value="800"`and see if this works for you. Technically it should work since you save radio btn value as `int` in the database.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ u want to see the javascript for the same??

Comment: No, the PHP code which deals with $_POST["other_field"]

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ this is the wonder.. this field is opened by javascript.. only and no extra php for the same..

Comment: What is your expected result? When you insert "other" to an int database field it's correct that it's casted to 0.

Comment: @TobiasZander u actually don t understand the obvjective of the question..

Comment: @TobiasZander on clicking on "other" a new field is to be opened and the value is being entered into this field.. and that value is to be taken to database..

Comment: And do you have a php code snippet, which is setting the $choice_no to $_POST['txtNumber'] if txtNumber=='other'=

Comment: @TobiasZander i thought of making that as the final solution in my mind.. i was looking for the alternative... but anyways.. thats the last option of all.. thanks dude.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined value for other field checkbox. use this maybe it will help you.

```
 <input type="text" name="other_field" id="other_field" value="value" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
```

Comment: Does not need `text` fields to define `value` property, gets what the input has.